# Replacing a particular number - For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
List<String> l1_0 = new ArrayList<String>(), l2_0 = new ArrayList<String>(),.....;
List<Integer> l1_1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(), l2_1 = new ArrayList<Integer>()......;
int lines1 = 0, lines2 = 0, lines3 = 0 .....;

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new FileReader("file/path//t1.txt"));


    while (s1.hasNext()) {
        l1_0.add(s1.next());
        l1_1.add(s1.nextInt());
        lines1++;
    }
    s1.close();

    func1(l1_0,l1_1,lines);
```

I have to perform same operation for 40 files.

Can we create a **for loop** to achieve it?
I am thinking of something along the lines of.

```
for (int i=1; i<= 40 ; i++)
{
    Scanner s[i] = new Scanner(new FileReader("file/path//t[i].txt"));
    while (s[i].hasNext()) {
        l[i]_0.add(s[i].next());
        l[i]_1.add(s[i].nextInt());
        lines[i]++;
    }
    s[i].close();
    func1(l[i]_0,l[i]_1,lines[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a loop. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Note that arrays are **zero-indexed**, and you do not need an array of scanners

Comment: As a new Java programmer, you should work on following Java conventions, including that for naming variables. Instead of `l1_0` it should be `file1Lines` or similar. (Eg. no snake-case, descriptive names, etc.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas : Thanks :)

Comment: @Dukeling "any help is appreciated" is pretty close to and to me has the same meaning as "Can someone help me?" Additionally, if you read the accepted answer in the meta question I linked it completely applies in this case. `Ask a programming question, not how to implement something`

Comment: @tnw Something for you to read.. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2yhjwe/why_are_experienced_programmers_so_hostile_toward/                                                        https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328269/should-i-be-nice-to-new-users/328271#328271

Comment: @Chid I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Did you interpret my comments here as hostile or rude? If that's the case I'm not really sure how.

Comment: @tnw In the spirit of avoiding duplication, my thoughts on that question is [posted as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303544/1711796).

Comment: Okay, I concede that I could have added some more detail to my comment explaining how the question needed improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to loop over your data 40 times. Once for each file.

```
for (int i=0; i< 40 ; i++)
{
    // Initializers for this one file
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    int lineCount = 0;

    String filename = "t" + i;

    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("file/path/" + filename + ".txt"))) {

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            strings.add(s.next());
            if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                nums.add(s.nextInt());
            }
            lineCount++;
        }
    }

    func1(strings,nums,lineCount);
}
```

Comment: As the user is new to Java, I would suggest demonstrating best practices in terms of closing that input stream via a try/finally or try-with-resources.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007.. It worked :) I realized this was a stupid ques!!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (int i=1; i<= 40 ; i++){
>     Scanner s[i] = new Scanner(new FileReader("file/path//t[i].txt"));
> }
> ```

In java there is no *implicit* `String` *pattern resolution*. That means you have to create yourself, the `String` representing new file names like this:

```
"file/path//t" + i + ".txt"
```

Or you may use `String.format()`:

```
String.format("file/path//t%d.txt",i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)